# Update a nested object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, shallow-copy, cloning

This is the original data

```
const data = {
    "field1": {
        "name": 'Anuv',
        "marks": {
            "eng": 43,
            "hindi": 23
        },
        "age": 21
    },
    "field2": {
        "school": 'DAV'
    }
}
```

I am trying to update the name

```
const updatedValue = {
    "field1": {
        "name": "Anuv Gupta"
    }
}
```

This is the expected data. It should have all the field and the updated name value as well.

```
const expectedData = {
    "field1": {
        "name": 'Anuv Gupta',
        "marks": {
            "eng": 43,
            "hindi": 23
        },
        "age": 21
    },
    "field2": {
        "school": 'DAV'
    }
}
```

I have tried using these

```
expectedData = Object.assign({}, data, updatedValue)
```

as well as

```
expectedData =  { ...data, ...updatedValue },
```

both of them returns this object

```
const obj = {
        "field1": {
            "name": 'Anuv Gupta',
        },
        "field2": {
            "school": 'DAV'
        }
    }
```

How do I fix this and get the expectedData object?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about mutating your original data you can just do:

```
data.field1.name = 'Anuv Gupta';
console.log(data);
```

If you don't want your original data to mutate, just clone it first and do the new value assignment:

```
const dataClone = structuredClone(data);
dataClone.field1.name = 'Anuv Gupta';
console.log(dataClone);
```

**Edit:**

Like others suggested you can also achieve that by spreading your data object into a new one like so:

```
const newData = {
  ...data,
  field1: {
    ...data.field1,
    name: 'Anuv Gupta',
  }
}
```

It works but it is not mutation proof as it only shallow clones the original data object - You can read more about shallow vs deep clone in this **[great blog post](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/70-3-ways-to-clone-objects/#shallow-clone-vs-deep-clone)**. if you care about not mutating your original data, I would use the second option I mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Avi's answer is good. Just to add one more method that is strictly immutable, you could do the following:

```
const expectedData = {
    ...data,
    "field1": {
        ...data.field1,
        "name": 'Anuv Gupta',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the name property directly:

```
data.field1.name = "new value"
```

If you're trying to avoid mutating the original data obj you can try:

```
data2 = Object.assign({}, data);
data2.field1.name = "new value"
```

Answer (score 0):

just change it directly using an Object property

```
data.field1.name = 'anuv Gupta'
```

and don't use quotes for object keys  just do this and it works just fine

```
const obj = {
        field1: {
            name: 'Anuv Gupta',
        },
        field2: {
            "school": 'DAV'
        }
    }
```